# Post BG subtraction(using opencv-python) and saving, output video is 2 GB. How to ensure it doesn't explode in size?

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, background-subtraction

*# Below piece of code is to read a video file called v1.mp4(size about 14MB), perform background subtraction on it, rotate the frame and save it.*

```
import cv2
import argparse
import datetime
import imutils
import time
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\Users\\212458792\\Music\\Downloads\\BasketVideos\\v1.mp4") #Open video file

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(detectShadows = True) #Create the background substractor

size = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))

# now creating video writer object  
bgsubvideo = cv2.VideoWriter('C:\\Users\\212458792\\Music\\Downloads\\BasketVideos\\bgsubvideo.avi', -1, 20.0,size)
#using any other codec like divx or xvid or mpeg for fourcc did create and video #file and write it, but i couldn't play the file. hence using -1
```

## perform background subtraction frame after frame

```
while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()#read a frame

    if ret==True:

        fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame) #Use the substractor
        cv.Flip(fgmask, flipMode=-1)
        bgsubvideo.write(fgmask)

    else:
        break

cap.release() #release video file
cv2.destroyAllWindows() #close all openCV windows
bgsubvideo.release()
```

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/22/writing-to-video-with-opencv/).